# Using clojure.contrib functions in slime REPL

Tags: clojure, slime

I want to use the functions in the clojure.contrib.trace namespace in slime at the REPL. How can I get slime to load them automatically? A related question, how can I add a specific namespace into a running repl?

On the clojure.contrib API it describes usage like this:

```
(ns my-namespace
  (:require clojure.contrib.trace))
```

But adding this to my code results in the file being unable to load with an "Unable to resolve symbol" error for any function from the trace namespace.

I use leiningen 'lein swank' to start the ServerSocket and the project.clj file looks like this

```
 (defproject test-project "0.1.0"
   :description "Connect 4 Agent written in Clojure"
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT"]
                  [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
   :dev-dependencies [[leiningen/lein-swank "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                      [swank-clojure "1.2.0"]])
```

Everything seems up to date, i.e. 'lein deps' doesn't produce any changes. So what's up?

Comment: You might want to mark Michal's answer as correct.

Comment: Tyler, you should mark Michal's answer as the accepted answer on this question since it seems to have solved your problem. Not only is it considered good form to do this, but it also gives your reputation score a little boost. Just click the check mark near the question's score.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You're getting "Unable to resolve symbol" exceptions because `:require` doesn't pull in any Vars from the given namespace, it only makes the namespace itself available.

   Thus if you `(:require foo.bar)` in your `ns` form, you have to write `foo.bar/quux` to access the Var `quux` from the namespace `foo.bar`. You can also use `(:require [foo.bar :as fb])` to be able to shorten that to `fb/quux`. A final possiblity is to write `(:use foo.bar)` instead; that makes all the Vars from `foo.bar` available in your namespace. Note that it is generally considered bad style to `:use` external libraries; it's probably ok within a single project, though.
2. Re: automatically making stuff available at the REPL:

   The `:require`, `:use` and `:refer` clauses of `ns` forms have counterparts in the `require`, `use` and `refer` functions in `clojure.core`. There are also macros corresponding to `:refer-clojure` and `:import`.

   That means that in order to make `clojure.contrib.trace` available at the REPL you can do something like `(require 'clojure.contrib.trace)` or `(require '[clojure.contrib.trace :as trace])`. Note that because `require` is a function, you need to quote the library spec. (`use` and `refer` also take quoted lib specs; `import` and `refer-clojure` require no quoting.)

   The simplest way to have certain namespaces available every time you launch a Clojure REPL (including when you do it with SLIME) is to put the appropriate `require` calls in `~/.clojure/user.clj`. See the [Requiring all possible namespaces](http://learnclojure.blogspot.com/2010/02/requiring-all-possible-namespaces.html) blog post by John Lawrence Aspden for a description of what you might put in `user.clj` to pull in *all* of contrib (something I don't do, personally, though I do have a `(use 'clojure.contrib.repl-utils)` in there).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Debugging in Emacs is much easier now.